# uploading a file to the database - symfony

Tags: symfony1

I'm using a form, that needs to be able to upload a PDF/Word doc file and insert it as blob data.

I am using Propel and SF1.4.

Is there a way I can do this? I've only ever seen uploading images to the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible, the method is the same as with the image files - after all, both are just blobs for the database.

However, you should reconsider this plan. Databases are not meant for such data, but filesystems are great! If you need permission control, store the files outside of your webroot, and have an action that:

- checks if the user has permission to download the file
- Sets the correct headers (content-type, content-disposition, etc.)
- serves the file via `readfile` or `fpassthru` or something similar

This would be faster and a lot easier to create and maintain.

Comment: Definitely agree on storing files in the file system. You can easily upload the file into a higher level directory (not web accessible) and store the location in the database. If you do decide to go the database route, I would create a table with only the blob data with a foreign key to an index table with the document title, type, description, etc. This will dramatically reduce overhead when querying the table but not needing the actual document itself.

Comment: Well I really need to upload the files to the database as Blobs. I cannot upload to the filesytem. Has anyone got a class/code that I can look through that may help?